# spaCy: Why is token.conjuncts only returning one conjunct, and not all the conjuncts?

Tags: nlp, spacy

According to https://spacy.io/api/token#conjuncts, token.conjuncts returns a tuple of coordinated tokens.

In the below sample of code, I'm expecting the code to go through each of the conjuncts and print something identifying them as a conjunct:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp("I am sad, depressed, miserable and lonely.")

sentences = list(doc.sents)

for sentence in sentences:
    print("Sentence: "+str(sentence))
    for child in sentence.root.children:
        for conjunct in child.conjuncts:
            print("This is a conjunct: "+conjunct.text)
```

However when I run the code, all I get is this:

> Sentence: I am sad, depressed, miserable and lonely.

> This is a conjunct: depressed

This is a surprise, because I understood that the words "depressed", "miserable", and "lonely" would all be conjuncts of the leftmost coordinated token (which in this case is "sad").

I have confirmed this by checking the dependency properties of each of those items, and spaCy does confirm that those are indeed conjuncts.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp("I am sad, depressed, miserable and lonely.")

for token in doc:
    print("This token: "+str(token)+" has dep property "+str(token.dep_))
```

Notice that each of "depressed", "miserable" and "lonely" *do* indeed have the property "conj":

[Screenshot of code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b92r4.png)

So it's surprising that token.conjuncts only seems to be recognising the first of the conjuncts. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

> However when I run the code, all I get is this:
>
> Sentence: I am sad, depressed, miserable and lonely.
>
> This is a conjunct: depressed

Try updating SpaCy, and/or using a larger English model (e.g. `en_core_web_lg` or `en_core_web_md`)

This will affect the accuracy of most NLP tasks.

Output using `en_core_web_lg`:

```
Sentence: I am sad, depressed, miserable and lonely.
This is a conjunct: depressed
This is a conjunct: miserable
This is a conjunct: lonely
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but I don't think this is correct. "sad" is a child of the root (which is "am"). "Depressed", "miserable", and "lonely" are conjuncts of "sad". I did try a variant of your proposal, but it still had the same issue.

Comment: @SanjayRedScarf Yes that makes sense. I've edited my answer.